# Comparing ALAssetGroupType in switch statement

Tags: iphone, switch-statement, objective-c-blocks, constant-expression

Hi I am calling ALAssetsLibrary's

```
-enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:block failureBlock:failure;
```

then inside the enumeration block i want to compare the type of group returned and add it to the relevant array. I have tried

```
^( ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop )
{
    NSLog(@"Group %@", group );
    ALAssetGroupType assetType = (ALAssetGroupType)[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyType];
    NSLog( @"Asset type %@", assetType );
    switch( assetType )
    {
        case ALAssetsGroupAplbum :
        NSLog( @"Found ALBUM" );
        [albums addObject:group];
        break;
    }
}
```

The Initial log traces out "Group ALAssetsGroup - Name:Photo Library, Type:Album, Assets count:177"

The next log is "Asset type 2"

but the third log never get's called.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`valueForProperty:` returns an object. In the case of `ALAssetsGroupPropertyType` it returns an ALAssetGroupType constant *wrapped in an NSNumber*. (See [docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsGroup_Class/Reference/Reference.html).)

So by casting to `ALAssetGroupType` you're using the object's memory address as your switch value. You need to get the underlying integer value of the NSNumber using `intValue`:

```
ALAssetGroupType assetType = 
 [[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyType] intValue];
```

Comment: Thanks That worked. I read the docs but I didn't realise that I had to get the underlying int.